# My GPU temperature is too high

Tags: windows-8, gpu, temperature

I have Nvidia GTX 560ti as graphic card, when I play games like Dota2, NBA, FIFA etc temperature goes to 90-99 degrees and I'm afraid it is going to damage it permanently or even damage other components. I changed thermal paste but it's still the same temperature as before. What am I supposed to do to fix temperature?

Comment: Fahrenheit or Celsius?

Comment: @Joe: I doubt he would be worried at 90 Fahrenheit ...

Comment: How are you measuring the temperatures exactly

Comment: @Lucas, I agree... but why assume when it never hurts to ask?

Comment: @Joe Celsius
Ramhound what do you mean? English is not my first language so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: How did you determine your GPU is running at those temperature and what scale did you use exactly, use Google, to translate if your still not sure what we are saying. You shouldn't need to change the thermal paste on a gpu odds are you applied to much

Comment: Well, I used HWM and MSI Afterburner, with fan speed going on on 70-80% temperature while playing NBA is 90-99 and DOTA2 85-95. Do I have to clear all dust from my computer case, like clean everything from GPU to Motherboard, unscrew everything and try to fix it like that? Will that help? :/

Comment: What is the baseline temperature when you are not playing games?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard With chrome, steam, garena and MSI afterburner on its 45-55 degrees celsius. (55% fan speed)

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to trouble-shooting a Graphics card, there isn't that much that can be down that you haven't already tried.

**The GTX 580TI should really not go higher than 97C. Anything higher than this can cause damage to the card, especially if sitting at it for extended periods of time**

The tool that I like to use for testing temperatures and controlling my cards is MSI Afterburner. But, any temp/fan control program will work.

The first thing to do would be to remove your system from your computer case (if its a small one), or have the computer case with it's cover off so you can see and hear the graphics card better. You can try the following:

1. Make sure your computer case is dust free. Use compressed air and clean out dust/dirt from the computer. In addition, remove the card from your board and make sure to clean the fan(s) on the card. Once this has been done, place the card back in the board and boot up your temp/fan program and test.
2. If the problem persists, our next step would be to remove the casing from the card, throughly clean the old thermal paste, re-apply and ensure that you get a solid connection between the card and casing unit. Allow a few minutes to dry and secure, place back into your system, and give it a test. I would also suggest turning your fans up a little higher in order to allow ample air-flow to continue to dry the thermal compound.
3. If still no luck, you can then look into buying an aftermarket cooler/heat sinks for your card. It isn't very common, but sometimes after long use, the stock heat sinks and coolers become 'warn-out' and they need to be replaced.

This would be best route in order to troubleshoot your card. You can also test your card in another computer that you have, or a friends computer and see if the temperature is the same. You could have a background program running that is causing the card to throttle up and increase temperature. Or, you could also have your card voltage not at stock. Getting a fresh install of the card will reset it.